# Pointer in structure memory allocation in initialization (c99)

Tags: c, pointers, c99

Lets assume that we've got a type:

```
typedef struct __BUFF_T__
{
    u_int8_t *buf;
    u_int32_t size;
}buff_t;
```

Is it correct allocating memory next way in c99?

```
buff_t a = {.size = 20,.buf = calloc(a.size,1)};
```

Compiler shows warning

> Variable 'data' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization

Memory's available and all, but are there some other non-warning options to do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From 6.7.9p23:

> The evaluations of the initialization list expressions are indeterminately sequenced with
>   respect to one another [...] (152) In particular, the evaluation order need not be the same as the order of subobject initialization.

So there is no guarantee that `a.size` is initialized at the point `calloc(a.size, 1)` is evaluated for the initialization of `a.buf`.

In this case, a suitable initializer would be a creation function:

```
inline buff_t create_buff(u_int32_t size) {
  return (buff_t) {.size = size, .buf = calloc(size, 1)};
}
buff_t a = create_buff(20);
```

This can't be used for static or file-scope objects; in that case a macro would be necessary (or, for example, a gcc statement expression, which could be used in a macro).

Answer (score 3):

The structure is not fully initialized until *after* the assignment of `a`, because you don't know in which *order* the expressions will be evaluated.

If you need to use a structure field to initialize another field in the same structure, you have to do it in separate steps.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong and particularly the statement: *because you don't know in which order the fields will be initialized*. C says the *initialization shall occur in initializer list order*. But as @ecatmur pointed out C says also that the *evaluations of the initialization list expressions are indeterminately sequenced with respect to one another* so that's why it is unspecified here.